# Can one sync reminders between iPhone and Mac using lightning cable?

Tags: ios, reminders

I am trying to avoid using iCloud… thanks for helping out!

Enabled calendar sync in Finder, calendars sync but not reminders.

Comment: Reminders aren't enabled in iCloud on the phone are they?  Just guessing.

Comment: Thanks for helping out… no they aren’t.